# How can I get a dirent struct from a string path?

Tags: c++, linux, dirent.h

If given a directory path in the form of a std::string, how can I get a dirent struct pointing to that directory?

I could start by getting a DIR* to the needed directory using opendir(). Then I could use readdir() on my DIR*, but that tries to return entries *within* the DIR*, not the DIR* itself.

So what is the appropriate way to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you need a `struct dirent`?

Comment: You could probably use `stat()` to get the information you want.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the directory entry *for the directory itself* within its *parent*, do this:

1. `stat(path)`.  Record `st_dev` and `st_ino`.
2. `stat(path + "/..")`. If this `st_dev` is not equal to the `st_dev` you got for `path`, `path` is a mount point, and the rest of what I'm about to say will not work.
3. `opendir(path + "/..")` gives you a `DIR*` for the parent directory.
4. `readdir` on that until you find a `dirent` with `d_ino` equal to the `st_ino` you saved in step 1.  That's the dirent you want.

The only piece of information you get from this algorithm that you can't get from just doing step 1, though, is the *name* of the directory within its parent directory.  And there's a much easier way to get that information: call [`realpath()`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/realpath/) to canonicalize the path, then extract the last component of the result.  No problems with mount points or symlinks, either.

Comment: This is so lame. Horrible for large directories. I use a dummy obj and build a hash with { path, name } to uniformly handle results.

Answer (score 1):

Repeat `readdir()` until you reach the `dirent` named `.`, which is the directory itself. To see this from the shell, type `ls -al`.